# I am unable to see/ preview Application settings while publishing app to azure

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, visual-studio-publish

I just started working with Azure platform. I tried to publish a azure function to Azure cloud to see how it works. I see that i am unable to preview the application settings is there anything I am missing ?

FYI I followed these steps: 
Right click project-> publish create a new profile or select already existed-> click Managed Application Settings

Answer (score 0):

My Json was not proper I gave values directly like this

{
"AzureFileShare": "somename",
"AzureWebJobsDashboard":"somename"

}

Instead of using following proper format.

{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
"AzureFileShare": "somename",

}
}